# Different ways to define lists and maps (Dart/Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart allows you to write either pattern A or pattern B below, which is the most common way to write it?

Also, how should I use patterns A and B differently?

```
// Pattern-A
List<String> list = [];
Map<String, String> map = {};
```

```
// Pattern-B
var list = <String>[];
var map = <String, String>{};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official recommendation, as per [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-type-annotating-initialized-local-variables), is to use `var`/`final` for *local* initialized variables

> AVOID type annotating initialized local variables.
> Linter rule: omit_local_variable_types
>
> Local variables, especially in modern code where functions tend to be small, have very little scope. Omitting the type focuses the reader’s attention on the more important name of the variable and its initialized value.
>
> DO:
>
> ```dart
> List<List<Ingredient>> possibleDesserts(Set<Ingredient> pantry) {
>  var desserts = <List<Ingredient>>[];
> ...
>
>  return desserts;
> }
> ```
>
> AVOID:
>
> ```dart
> List<List<Ingredient>> possibleDesserts(Set<Ingredient> pantry) {
>  List<Ingredient> desserts = <List<Ingredient>>[];
> ...
>
>  return desserts;
> }
> ```